# "I have class" or "I am having class" in context

Tags: present-continuous, stative-verbs

Let's say I am a student and at this very moment I am being taught math and someone is calling me and asks *what are you doing*. Is correct to say the following?

> I am having math class.

And by the way is there any difference in meaning between *have math class* and *have a math class*. If there isn't, then which one is more common?

Comment: *I am having* [or ***I'm in***] ***a**math class*. Idiomatically I think most people would include the article there, but it's not essential. We'd usually use the *continuous* form ***am having*** as a reply to *What are you doing **now**?*, but if the question had been "future-based" (for example, *What are you doing **after your lunch break**?*) we'd probably just use Simple Present (referencing a future activity ***currently*** planned for / expected).

Comment: My experience is that in most cases, the person will say "I'm in [a] math class", rather than "I'm having...". The use of "have" seems to be more common when discussing it as an event rather than what one is/will be doing - "I have math at 11:00." or "I had Thermogoddamics last semester, and if I never have it again, it will be exactly twenty minutes too soon."

Answer (score -1):

"I am having math class" says that you are presently participating in that math class.
"I have math class" says that math class is something you will do in the future.

Comment: In your experience have you often heard people (native English speakers)  say "I am having math class"?

Comment: If we are saying that they are in math class already, I normally hear people say "I am in math class."